# Is there way to create reference link in PDF automatically?

Tags: pdf

I am not familiar with PDF format, but many papers (.pdf) cite references.

For example, in this [paper](http://www.bracha.org/oopsla90.pdf)

> ... for Beta and Smalltalk [3].
>
> **References**
>
> [3] Cook, W. A Denotational Semantics of Inheri-
> tance. PhD thesis, Brown University, 1989.

Is there way (tool) to create reference link in PDF automatically?

I hope to jump to the `[3]`'s References page by clicking the `[3]`.

Very thanks.

Comment: Visit this website, this explains it in detail. https://erinwrightwriting.com/internal-links-in-pdfs-with-adobe-acrobat/

Comment: @TontyTon This is to create a link manually, I hope it can be created automatically.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood.